# Как подключить внешний скрипт к моему расширению с версией манифеста V3?

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Мне необходимо подключить сторонний скрипт, расположенный на определённом сайте к моему расширению. Предположим, что это просто стандартный скрипт, я точно знаю его адрес, но при попытке подключения я получаю ошибку: Refused to load the script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback. Как мне исправить её?

Моё расширение на данный момент имеет такой вид `manifest.json`:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "action": { "default_popup": "popups.html" },
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "background": { "service_worker": "test.js" },
    "description": "test extension",
    "permissions": ["storage","scripting"],
    "manifest_version": 3
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950009/chrome-extension-refused-to-load-the-script-because-it-violates-the-following-c

Comment: @Mike, спасибо вам большое, но это для манифеста второй версии, а мне хотелось бы увидеть решение для актуальной 3-ей версии, если такое имеется.

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Загрузка удаленных скриптов не поддерживается в V3.